# mysql select keywords from 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql

i have this problem right here..
I got 3+id rows in table, 3 of them are for keywords:

```
kw1, kw2, kw3
```

And then i have values

```
$kw1, $kw2, $kw3
```

so table looks like

```
id | kw1 | kw2 | kw3 |
----------------------
1  | $kw1| $kw2| $kw3|
....
```

By this query i can select only if all 3 of them matches

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE kw1='".$kw1."' OR kw2 = '".$kw2."' OR kw3 = '".$kw3."'
```

I also tried to make it something like this:

```
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE 
 (kw1='".$kw1."' OR kw2 = '".$kw2."' OR kw3 = '".$kw3."') OR
 (kw1='".$kw3."' OR kw2 = '".$kw2."' OR kw3 = '".$kw1."') OR
 (kw1='".$kw2."' OR kw3 = '".$kw2."' OR kw3 = '".$kw1."') OR
 ... ETC
```

But i wanted to ask you if there is some other way - "smarter" one?

Thank you!

Comment: You should rethink your database design - I think the keywords should have their own table. What if you want to have 4 keywords for some item?

Comment: @user1615903 Or you can concat the keywords into one field with a separator. '|kw1|kw2|kw3|' - this allows you to LIKE '%|$query|%' or explode('|', $db_result). But then suggesting DB structure changes is usually pointless, there is too much code revolving around the current structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your syntax by using `in`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE kw1 in ($kw1, $kw2, $kw3) or
      kw2 in ($kw1, $kw2, $kw3) or
      kw3 in ($kw1, $kw2, $kw3)
```

By the way, you can have columns in the `in` list as well as constants:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE $kw1 in (kw1, kw2, kw3) or
      $kw2 in (kw1, kw2, kw3) or
      $kw3 in (kw1, kw2, kw3)
```

If you want where all three match, then change the `or` to `and`.  (Your code and your description seem to differ on whether you want *any* to match or *all* to match.)

Comment: Thanks, this is briliant answer!

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? Are these search queries or something similar? If are are trying to search you can use [MySQL full text search in BOOLEAN MODE](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/full-text-search-using-mysql-full-text-search-capabilities/).

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE kw1='".$kw1."' OR kw2 = '".$kw2."' OR kw3 = '".$kw3."'
```

This query will match even if only kw1 is equals to $kw1, you should use AND statement of you want the three of them matched.